# Inline SVG - How to Put an image.svg onto a Page

Tags: html, image, svg

I'm only new to Inline SVG and from my reading it sounds really interesting. I expecially like the way it can maintain multiple colors (which are currently lost ith icon fonts).

Following is an graphic created in Adobe Illistrator and exported as an SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="265.427px" height="105.59px" viewBox="0 0 265.427 105.59" enable-background="new 0 0 265.427 105.59"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Edit_Button_1_">
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="132.7144" y1="10.8496" x2="132.7144" y2="90.4107">
        <stop  offset="0.099" style="stop-color:#F5F6F6"/>
        <stop  offset="0.8267" style="stop-color:#E9E9E9"/>
    </linearGradient>

        <rect x="0.474" y="0.474" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#CDCCCC" stroke-width="0.9479" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="264.479" height="104.643"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <polygon fill="#6F6F6F" points="27.945,62.067 20.953,83.479 42.234,76.368                   "/>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <path fill="#6F6F6F" d="M67.206,22.81c3.765-3.827,9.988-3.805,14.024,0.166c4.024,3.969,4.154,10.186,0.39,14.013
                        L67.206,22.81z"/>
                </g>
                <polygon fill="#6F6F6F" points="45.999,72.609 31.698,58.312 62.865,27.153 77.16,41.45               "/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 100.8813 74.3232)" fill="#6F6F6F" font-family="'Verdana'" font-size="57.8802">EDIT</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm confussed on how to put this onto a HTML page. Do I just copy the `<svg>` to `</svg>` tags?

Is there any conversion/optimisation required?

I've also read about defining SVG Files for later use: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

What are the advantages/disadvantages of this?

thankyou so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You only need to copy the `<svg>` section.  The XML pre-amble lines (`<?xml>` and `<!DOCTYPE>`) are not required.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/txav2pve/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. that seems quiet amazing (will test tonight) as its so much less data required to send to the data. Eg: the original image might be 5KB but the text above is only small amount of characters... that really speeds up a site :) Am I correct there?

Comment: By "the original image", do you mean a PNG or JPEG etc?  Then yes.  It depends on the image.  You could have a bitmap image that is smaller than the SVG used to generate it, but in general yes.  Note that there are some issues to consider when using SVGs.  For instance IE didn't support SVG until IE9.